# Add Animation in React Native Bottom Tabs

Tags: react-native, react-animated

Hello I want to add animation in React Native Bottom Tabs, I have used React Navigation 4.

**Expected behaviour:when user click on plus icon the bottom sheet like open and when user click on doctor appointment then doctorAppointment screen will be open.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please try this FABs Component it will help you , thanks

https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#fabs-def-headref

Comment: No Its not fab Its React Navigation

Comment: Yes you are absolutely Right , but you can use custom component for Bottom tab and handle this easily   thanks:-)